# Deep learning how to assign probability scores to the classes

Tags: python, keras

I am running deep learning with `keras`. I need to assign probabilities to the predicted classes of a binary classification. The command `model.predict()` is providing an output which is an array consisting of a single column with probability scores. I need to sort both of the 2 classes according to their probability scores. In case of SVM, there is a 2d array provided that may look like this:

```
array([[1.73012153e-01, 8.26987847e-01],
[9.20157632e-01, 7.98423679e-02],
[1.65736191e-01, 8.34263809e-01],
[9.61620647e-01, 3.83793535e-02]]
```

for the following list of classes:

```
1
0
1
0
```

By comparing the list of the classes with this array one concludes that class 1 is being assigned the probability scores from the second entries of the array and the class 0 from the first entries. Both classes can thus be assigned scores greater then 0.5. It is clear that both entries sum up to one.

Can somebody provide a comment and explain how I can find the probability scores for the class 0 and 1 ? By setting a threshold of 0.5 and claiming that class 1 is the one with probability score greater than 0.5 and class 0 the one with probability score less than 0.5 leads to having class 1 being assigned high probability scores and class 0 low probability scores. Since in my task I need to chose hits from both classes with high probability scores, I thus do not know how to proceed in the case of `keras`. Here is how the output of `model.predict()` in `keras` looks like:

```
array([[6.6122383e-01],
[6.3882202e-02],
[9.7862136e-01],
[3.9379299e-03],
[4.2064726e-02],
[9.7605175e-07],
[5.5374026e-01]]
```

The code that I use to generate the model is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout 
model = Sequential()  
model.add(Dense(30,activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(.5)) 
model.add(Dense(15,activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(.5)) #binary classifcation 
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')) 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam') 
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,epochs=600,validation_data=  (x_test,y_test), verbose = 0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Keras does not provide a single probability, your model does, and keras just does what you tell it to do.

Comment: How should I tell `keras` to provide me the array that I get when I use SVM ?

Comment: First you should define the behavior mathematically, not just imitating an SVM, and second, you need a model that outputs two probabilities, and you did not include any information about your model.

Comment: I think what you want is to do multi-label classfication? Where both classes can be predicted at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DNN with sigmoid activation function in the last layer would give one array of probabilities, you can construct the class column by yourself:

```
df["class_1_prob"]=predicted_prob
df["class_0_prob"]=1-predicted_prob

df["target_class_0"]=[0 if x <0.5 else 1 for x in predicted_prob]
df["target_class_1"]=np.abs(1-df["target_class_0"])
```

Comment: Thanks. But given that I need to sort out the two classes according to the probability scores, It turns out that class 0 will be assigned probability scores less than 0.5 and the class 1 probability scores greater than 0.5. which is not what I need. I need to select both classes according to their scores. The higher the probability score the higher the confidence for that class. In SVM one can use the command `classifier.predict_proba()` to get a 2d array. Both classes can thus be assigned probability scores greater than 0.5. Is there an equivalent command in `keras`?

Comment: More precisely, do I have to chose for this aim some activation different from sigmoid ?

Comment: all what you need is to create another column with 1-prob for the other class, see the edited answer

Comment: you can use softmax with converting your target single column to two separated columns. But mathematically speaking softmax and sigmoid are the same thing in case of two classes, softmax is used when we have more than two classes.